# GTM VideoURL additional parameter "ebc"

Tags: google-analytics, youtube, google-tag-manager

I'm using GTM Video Trigger to track embedded YouTube video plays.
And in my GTM Tag, I'm using Video URL as the Label.

In most cases, I would get https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=[videoID], which is expected.

But at times, I also get an additional parameter "ebc" like below:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=[videoID]&ebc=ANyPxKq6wOyn-_68ADUNNWoKXt0cBO8Qg5OjjtgtzJd-kXCsjVnRJHOn02D_D0DzQpK2WJZinX-EZmo9XidB74X1RRogbztP3A

As this is affecting my GA reporting, I'm hoping to ensure the Video URL value is consistent (without the ebc parameter). Help, please.

Answer (score 0):

You can add a Search and Replace filter to your Google Analytics on the Event Label field (leave the Replace String blank):

Search String: `&ebc=[^&]`

Make sure you apply this to a test view first before applying to your reporting view, but that should do it.